# how free of memory happen in this case?

Tags: c, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>
void func(int arr[],int xNumOfElem)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<xNumOfElem; j++)
    {
       arr[j] = j + arr[j];
       printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main()
{

    int *a,k;
    a = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int)*10);


    for(k = 0; k<10; k++)
    {
        a[k] = k;
        printf("%d\t",a[k]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    func(a,10); //Func call

    free(a);                                                                                                                              
}
```

Inside the the function "func" who will allocate/deallocate memory for dynamic array "arr".

arr is an function argument.

Answer (score 1):

You don't pass an array, you only pass the pointer to an int. The line

```
void func(int arr[],int xNumOfElem)
```

is just an other way to write

```
void func(int* arr,int xNumOfElem)
```

the compiler itself can't allocate memory for a copy of a, as the size of a is dynamic and therefor unknown to the compiler. print the values of a after the call to func to see that a has changed.

To get a copy change your func method to:

```
void func(int const* const b,int xNumOfElem)
{
    int* arr = malloc(sizeof(int)*xNumOfElem);
    memcpy(b,arr,xNumOfElem);
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<xNumOfElem; j++)
    {
       arr[j] = j + arr[j];
       printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    free(arr);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for ur feedback. I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

One need not allocate memory for array `arr` in the function `fun`. The memory for array is allocated in the `main` function before the `fun` is called. Also `main` is deallocating the memory once it is done using the memory; so `fun` need not do deallocating as well.

Comment: no it is pass by value if u alter it contents inside the function it wont reflect in the main function. So somehow memory is created for "arr". ???

Comment: Arrays are passed by address. If you make changes to `arr` inside function `fun` it will be reflected in `main`. Give it a try. This shows there is just one copy of the entire array which was allocated in `main`.

Comment: No It wont reflect in this case!!, Print the conetents of actual array after calling function. I verified it.

Comment: @Riyaz: You've **not** tried it correctly. Take a look at this: http://www.ideone.com/YhMtG

Answer (score 0):

Think of it this way:

```
void func(int arr[],int xNumOfElem)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<xNumOfElem; j++)
    {
       arr[j] = j + arr[j];
       printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
void func(int *arr /* look here */,int xNumOfElem)
{
    int j;
    for(j=0; j<xNumOfElem; j++)
    {
       arr[j] = j + arr[j];
       printf("%d\t",arr[j]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I got this doubt because in some hdl laguage array can be passed by value or pass by reffrence. Also i made mistake in this c file by asigning a[k] = k; after calling function func(). So values are are getting changed again here. OK I will close thiss issue. Thanks!!